# ignited datatables search not working with server side processing

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

Data is showing fine, but search filter not working.
Im using Codeigniter with Ignited Datatables.

Here is my HTML code or View file you may say.

```
                        <table id="ManageForms" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Form Name</th>
                            <th>Form Path</th>
                            <th>Form CI Path</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
<tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ManageForms').dataTable({

                "bServerSide":true,
                "bProcessing":true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bFilter":true,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "sAjaxSource": "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/listForms_DT/",
                "iDisplayLength": 2,
                "aLengthMenu": [[2, 25, 50, -1], [2, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "sEcho": 1,
                "columns":[
                    {data:"FormName"},
                    {data:"FormPath"},
                    {data:"FormCIPath"},
                    { "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button>Edit</button>",
                        "targets": -1
                    }
                ],
                'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
                    $.ajax ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type'    : 'POST',
                        'url'     : sSource,
                        'data'    : aoData,
                        'success' : fnCallback
                    }); //end of ajax
                }

            });
        } );
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
 function listForms_DT(){
$this->datatables->select('FormID, FormName, FormPath, FormCIPath')
         ->unset_column('FormID')
         ->from('sys_forms');
     echo $this->datatables->generate();
}//end of list_forms_view

}
```

The Ignited Datatables Library Function, where it seems to have the problem

```
public function generate($output = 'json', $charset = 'UTF-8')
{
  if(strtolower($output) == 'json')
    $this->get_paging();

  $this->get_ordering();
  $this->get_filtering();
  return $this->produce_output(strtolower($output), strtolower($charset));
}

/**
* Generates the LIMIT portion of the query
*
* @return mixed
*/
private function get_paging()
{
  $iStart = $this->ci->input->post('iDisplayStart');
  $iLength = $this->ci->input->post('iDisplayLength');

  if($iLength != '' && $iLength != '-1')
    $this->ci->db->limit($iLength, ($iStart)? $iStart : 0);
}

/**
* Generates the ORDER BY portion of the query
*
* @return mixed
*/
private function get_ordering()
{

  $Data = $this->ci->input->post('columns');


  if ($this->ci->input->post('order'))
    foreach ($this->ci->input->post('order') as $key) 
      if($this->check_cType())
        $this->ci->db->order_by($Data[$key['column']]['data'], $key['dir']);
      else
        $this->ci->db->order_by($this->columns[$key['column']] , $key['dir']);

}

/**
* Generates a %LIKE% portion of the query
*
* @return mixed
*/
private function get_filtering()
{
  $mColArray = $this->ci->input->post('iColumns');
  $sWhere = '';
  $search = $this->ci->input->post('search');
  $sSearch = $this->ci->db->escape_like_str(trim($search['value']));
  $columns = array_values(array_diff($this->columns, $this->unset_columns));

  if($sSearch != '' && $sSearch != 0)
    for($i = 0; $i < count($mColArray); $i++)
      if($mColArray[$i]['searchable'] == 'true' )
        if($this->check_cType())
          $sWhere .= $this->select[$mColArray[$i]['data']] . " LIKE '%" . $sSearch . "%' OR ";
        else
          $sWhere .= $this->select[$this->columns[$i]] . " LIKE '%" . $sSearch . "%' OR ";


  $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, '', -3);

  if($sWhere != '')
    $this->ci->db->where('(' . $sWhere . ')');

  // TODO : sRangeSeparator

  foreach($this->filter as $val)
    $this->ci->db->where($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
}
```

Now finally the Post Parameters

```
bRegex  false
bRegex_0    false
bRegex_1    false
bRegex_2    false
bRegex_3    false
bSearchable_0   true
bSearchable_1   true
bSearchable_2   true
bSearchable_3   true
bSortable_0 true
bSortable_1 true
bSortable_2 true
bSortable_3 true
iColumns    4
iDisplayLength  2
iDisplayStart   0
iSortCol_0  0
iSortingCols    1
mDataProp_0 FormName
mDataProp_1 FormPath
mDataProp_2 FormCIPath
mDataProp_3 
sColumns    ,,,
sEcho   1
sSearch 
sSearch_0   
sSearch_1   
sSearch_2   
sSearch_3   
sSortDir_0  asc
```

The problem where is seems to me is that my datatables is posting sSearch but in the ignitedDatables, it is looking for search

Ignited Datatables library, get_filtering function.
    $search = $this->ci->input->post('search');

so i tried changing it to

```
$search = $this->ci->input->post('sSearch');
```

after that my datatables even stopped me showing the data it was showing before. so i had to reverse back to search..

Please if anyone have any expertise, explain me what is it i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

was using the wrong ignited dataTables Library.

it seems that there are two versions of ignited DataTables library on github both by different users.

using this below library exactly fits the parameters that my dataTables send to server.

```
https://github.com/cryogenix/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement the igniter tables and even after realize that i was using the wrong library, my table just load - forever - but the data did not appear. i was developing using the 'development' environment _ something whispered in my ear (maybe the devil) and said to me test it in the production environment and voilá, it worked!  I'm new in CI, i don't know why this happened.

Comment: in addiction, i changed my index.php to at least see the errors. define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); case 'testing':
  case 'production':
                        //instead of this
   //error_reporting(0);
   //ini_set("display_errors", 0);  //<-----
   
                        //i left this way, and its ok!
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1); //<-----